# Logistic Regression with Interaction Odds Ratio Interpretation

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, interpretation, odds-ratio

I just want to make sure I'm interpreting my results correctly. See below.
The interaction terms confuse me when interpreting. Am I correct in saying that the odds ratio is "comparing" Purebred dogs (S/N yes/no) with Non-purebred dogs with the same spay/neuter status? Thanks!

[image: Results]

Answer (score 1):

Yes one odds ratio compares pure bred dogs spayed or neutered with non pure bred dogs spayed or neutered and the second compares pure bred dog not spayed or neutered with non pure bred dogs not spayed or neutered